# How to finish a Plesk update on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, updates, plesk

So I have Plesk installed on ubuntu 16.04.06 and recently an update failed with this error:

```
ERROR: Installation will not continue
The apg-get failed with the following message:
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-4.4.0-1085-aws : Depends: linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1085 but it is not going to be installed
Not all packages were installed.
Please contact product technical support.
```

so I ran `apt-get -f install`

and it seems to have all ran correctly, output ending with

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1085-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1085-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1084-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1084-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1083-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1083-aws
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1052-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1052-aws
done
```

My question is what do I do now to finish updating my server?

I do have auto-update turned on:

[image: plesk update screen]

From comments: Running `sudo ls /var/cache/apt/archives/*deb`
results in

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1085_4.4.0-1085.96_all.deb
```

Running `df -i`
results in

```
Filesystem       Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            1019735     327  1019408    1% /dev
tmpfs           1021731     612  1021119    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     20480000 5482104 14997896   27% /
tmpfs           1021731       1  1021730    1% /dev/shm
```

Comment: Have you tried to restart the Plesk service?  However, it does not appear the command, did anything except find the images.

Comment: My server is hosting live sites so I don't think I can restart it. There was more to the output, but that's all that I copied before my session timed out.

Comment: adding a screenshot with the plesk settings

Comment: How else do you expect to be running the upgraded installation without restarting the Plesk service?  Any event try **sudo ls /var/cache/apt/archives/*deb** and provide a formatted output.  If the output is more then 5 files, omit anything past, the 5th file.  Also provide **df -i**

Comment: I don't know, thats why I'm asking questions, so I can learn what I should do.

Comment: i ran both of those commands and updated the question

Comment: What is the date on the .deb file?  If the date is recent, it appears, your system is ready to be restarted.

Comment: You still have not indicated if you have restarted the service.  You only indicated you were not willing to do that.

Comment: I'm thinking I'm looking at the wrong thing, I think I should be figuring out why the auto-update feature isn't working, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the plesk auto-updater. There was a bug in one of the updates. (I can't find the bug number now), but it has been fixed.